# manage the focus in a custom view

Tags: android, view, focus

I am implementing a custom `View` and I want to manage the focus so that when it's in the focused state it is drawed in a different way than in the normal state. I know that I probably have to override `onFocusChanged`, but how do I get that method called when the view should lose the focus, for example when there is a tap outside of it? I have searched in the docs but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The method onFOcusChanged is called every time that the focus of your view is changed, so, if the user tap outside your view you will receive a call in onFocusChanged.

The first parameter show if you gain the focus or lose it.

```
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean gainFocus, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {}
```

Comment: I have already tried to override that method but it's never called, so I guess the problem is GAINING the focus. How do I do that? i tried to set focusableInTouchMode = true but it does nothing.

Comment: try to set the listener manually like this.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener ....)